What are some examples of modern, non-academic philosophy questions?
Here are some ancient philosophy questions that the Ancient Greeks posed:

How many grains of sand make up a pile?
If you take a ship, replace its parts (starboard, stern, oars, etc...) one-by-one with bedazzled components, so that the end result is completely new, is it still the same ship?
What does it mean to be a good person?

Now what are some philosophy questions for the modern man, who has different challenges from the ancient man, along the same lines as the ancient philosophers? Here are some suggestions recommended by autocomplete:

How do you answer someone when he asks you "how do I look"?
What is the definition of a man or woman?
How do you measure, sort, and compare the overall qualities of general AI's?


Pretty much every question that can be asked simply and in common language was already asked in the pre-modern world.

Some that come to mind:

If evolution is true and AGIs are on the horizon and AGIs are the next step in evolution after humanity, should we along with the cosmos celebrate when we become AGIs' cattle and fodder? (See matrix)

For economics, successful economics means growth; for ecology, unbounded growth is healthy only in an unbounded world whereas in a finite word it means depredation. How do humans choose between economics and ecology?

Our political philosophy today is incorrigibly Westphalian, ie from the 17th century. Yet today's social media are like countries, in that they are more powerful than a majority of countries listed in the UN, yet they brazenly crosscut traditional country-boundaries. {Eg. A 21 year old college student can be jailed for the «crime» of receiving a tweet from Greta Thunberg}. Do country-boundaries mean anything today?

In these social media, which are the de facto news sources of our time what/how/who is free-speech, hate/violent-speech, censorship? If censorship or at least some curbs are needed according to the laws of which country should they operate — the country where they are incorporated or the country(s) with maximum users? If there are no curbs who takes the responsibility for violence that results?



I find it hilarious that a question as fundamental to philosophy as this gets closed. So "community-wikied" it. Anyone can add what they like AFAIC
